# Pyramid in C# Clarifications

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C#, learning for loops. In the book I am learning from it tells us to build a pyramid with asterisks. Completely stomped, I looked at the answer key and became even more confused.This is the code from the key:

This is the answer code

[image: This is the answer code]

There is no real step by step example of what the code is doing and I do not understand how the programmer came to this solution or what they are explaining in the comments. Can someone breakdown how this down for me?

Comment: It literally just prints out the correct amount of spaces then the correct amount of stars based on what row it is printing. the outer forloop detemines row, the first nested for loop prints the correct amount of spaces and the second nested for loop prints the correct amount of stars

Comment: You dont want to be copying the code anyway, the best thing to do is just think carefully about exactly how you might solve this problem. I also remember doing this when I had just begun programming.

Comment: Is there a specific area you are confused with? All that comments says it all

Comment: The programmer came to the idea by analyzing the problem: How does this pyramid look? How does one line differ from the next? Can I derive a formula for the changing parts to calculate it from the known parts (height, current line, ...)? If you ask yourself such questions and read the comments in the code again, you will see, that the author tried to guide you.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev  I don't understand how he came up with the formulas for the spaces and asterisks for loops.

Comment: Formula == Maths == Pattern. Find the pattern and apply

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Post code as text, so it can be copied/pasted/edited/searched.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Start by visualizing the desired output:

```
 |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|
0| | | | |*| | | | |
1| | | |*|*|*| | | |
2| | |*|*|*|*|*| | |
3| |*|*|*|*|*|*|*| |
4|*|*|*|*|*|*|*|*|*|
```

Then break it down into how to print each line.

```
Line 0 has 4 spaces then 1 star  (and optionally 4 more spaces).
Line 1 has 3 spaces then 3 stars (and optionally 3 more spaces).
Line 2 has 2 spaces then 5 stars (and optionally 2 more spaces).
```

Then realize it's two separate issues.

```
What comes next in this sequence (and why): 4,3,2,?
What comes next in this sequence (and why): 1,3,5,?
```

Then you code it.

```
NumberOfSpaces = 5 - lineNumber -1
NumberOfStars = 2 * lineNumber + 1
```

Put that in a loop with lineNumber going from 0 to 4 and you are done, and that is what he did.  This program does the same thing:

```
namespace PositiveOrNegative
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      for(int lineNumber = 0; lineNumber < 4; lineNumber++)
      {
        int NumberOfSpaces = 5 - lineNumber - 1;
        int NumberOfStars = 2 * lineNumber + 1;

        for(int space = 0; space < NumberOfSpaces; space++)
        {
          Console.Write(" ");
        }

        for(int star = 0; star < NumberOfStars; star++)
        {
          Console.Write("*");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

And if you hate loops, then you could do this:

```
namespace PositiveOrNegative
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int lineNumber;
      int NumberOfSpaces;
      int NumberOfStars;

      lineNumber = 0;
      NumberOfSpaces = 5 - lineNumber - 1;
      NumberOfStars = 2 * lineNumber + 1;
      Console.WriteLine(new String(' ',NumberOfSpaces) + new String('*',NumberOfStars));

      lineNumber = 1;
      NumberOfSpaces = 5 - lineNumber - 1;
      NumberOfStars = 2 * lineNumber + 1;
      Console.WriteLine(new String(' ',NumberOfSpaces) + new String('*',NumberOfStars));

      lineNumber = 2;
      NumberOfSpaces = 5 - lineNumber - 1;
      NumberOfStars = 2 * lineNumber + 1;
      Console.WriteLine(new String(' ',NumberOfSpaces) + new String('*',NumberOfStars));

      lineNumber = 3;
      NumberOfSpaces = 5 - lineNumber - 1;
      NumberOfStars = 2 * lineNumber + 1;
      Console.WriteLine(new String(' ',NumberOfSpaces) + new String('*',NumberOfStars));

      lineNumber = 4;
      NumberOfSpaces = 5 - lineNumber - 1;
      NumberOfStars = 2 * lineNumber + 1;
      Console.WriteLine(new String(' ',NumberOfSpaces) + new String('*',NumberOfStars));

      }
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer to using 0-based indexes instead of 1-based so the formulas matched up with the original answer better.

Answer (score 0):

I have explained the pyramid logic in the program. Look for comments below.

Core logic:

First loop: Set loop count as number for rows in pyramid
Second loop (space): Set loop count as spaces required before * in each row
Third loop (star):Set loop count as * required in each row

See comments in below program for details.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /// This for loop is for keeping the number of rows in pyramid (height) and - 
        /// iterate through each rows to print the pyramid using *
        for(int row=0;row<5;row++)
        {
            /// This loop is used add spaces before *
            /// Core logic - Set number of loop (space max) as number spaces required
            /// Row 1: Adding 4 spaces before * (space max limit = 5 - 0 - 1)
            /// Row 2: Adding 3 spaces before * (space max limit = 5 - 1 - 1)
            /// Row 3: Adding 2 spaces before * (space max limit = 5 - 2 - 1)
            /// And goes on like above pattern
            for (int space=0;space<5-row-1;space++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }

            /// This loop is used add *
            /// Building the * pattern, logic in below comments
            /// Core logic - Set number of loop (star max) as number for stars required
            /// First row: Stars required = 1, (star max limit = 0 * 2 + 1 = 1)
            /// Second row: Stars required = 3, (star max limit = 1 * 2 + 1 = 3)
            /// Third row: Stars required = 5, (star max limit = 2 * 2 + 1 = 5)
            /// Fourth row: Stars required = 7, (star max limit = 3 * 2 + 1 = 7)
            /// And goes on like above pattern
            for (int star = 0; star < row * 2 + 1; star++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```